# Which is best Model to implement Question Answering System

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I Would like to know or get a clear picture of Question answering system. How to find which is the best model to implement. I don't need it to be any domain specific.

Moreover, I find all models looks same to me, it may be IR-based question answering system, Knowledge-Based Question answering system, Ontology-based system or few other systems.

Please guide me which one is best and what all approaches to be followed to implement those models.